# How to set an ImageView in the corner and keep the position?

Tags: android, android-layout, background, imageview, android-imageview

I want to add an `ImageView` as background of my layout. I want the `ImageView` in the bottom end corner. I got this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:rotation="-15"
        android:translationX="-180dp"
        android:translationY="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, the result is different depending on the screen:

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

I think my problem is because I am using `android:translationX` and `android:translationY` with static values, but I am not able to find a solution to this.

I expect the image to have always same position, this is, to always show same portion of the image and maintain the aspect ratio, so it autoscale itself depending on the screen.

How can achieve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using static values for translation? That is definitely causing the image to be out of the SurfaceView. Remember that in android, you have your (0,0) coordinate in the top left corner, so defining -180 in X will set the image backwards in the left side.

Comment: Hi @AlexRivas thank you for replying. Because I only want to show a portion of the image, not the whole image, therefore I am trying to "hide" some part of the left side of image.

Comment: Yes I understand. You can calculate the translationX depending the device screen size. I will provide an example.

Comment: What about cutting the logo? And only use the part that you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
fun translateImageView(imageView: ImageView) {
    val screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val translationX = (-1 * screenWidth / 3.5f) // adjust the 3.5f value to suit your needs
    imageView.translationX = translationX
}
```

Here's what this function does:

- The translateImageView function takes an ImageView as a parameter.
- The Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels call returns the width of the screen in pixels.
- The translationX variable is calculated as a negative fraction of the screen width. In this case, the image is translated to the left by 1/3.5th of the screen width.
- The translationX value is set on the ImageView using the translationX property.

Adjust the value of 3.5f to suit your needs. A higher value will move the image more to the left, and a lower value will move it less to the left.

The code uses the `Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels` call to get the width of the screen in pixels. Since the screen width is measured in pixels, it is not affected by the device's pixel density (ppi) or screen size.

The `translationX` value is calculated as a negative fraction of the screen width, which means that the image will be translated by a fixed amount relative to the screen width, regardless of the device's pixel density. This fixed amount is calculated to be a negative fraction of the screen width, which means that the image will always be translated to the left by the same amount, regardless of the screen size or pixel density.

Therefore, the `ImageView` will always be translated to the same position in all devices, regardless of their pixel density, screen size, or aspect ratio.

PD: I haven't tried that solution. But it should give you a start.